# ¿Cuál es el significado de esta frase: "Me caerían 30 años"?

Tags: significado, significado-en-contexto

I am a student of Spanish. I am planning to watch a Spanish tv series in native Spanish, *Money Heist* (La Casa de Papel)

This is a sentence from the opening scene:

> Me **caerían** 30 años

This wasn't accompanied by anything else. I already know the verb **caer** but I couldn't figure out what she meant by it. She was running from the law and explaining her criminal background.

Comment: The image is like something falling on a person from above. As in: x would come down on me. But, to translate it for the movie, it's I'd get 30 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a colloquial way of saying “I would get 30 years (jail time)”. The verb *caer*, here, could be approximately translated into English as “to happen” or “to befall”, although depending on the context, it could also mean “to receive as deserved punishment” or “to get dealt by luck”. So you can think of it like this: ***“Me caerían 30 años”* = “30 years jail time would befall me”.**

Comment: Typo? _befell_ is past, _befall_ seems better. Perhaps _I will be landed with 30 years_ has the same flavour as _caer_ although it it not a very natural phrase.

Comment: @mdewey Not a typo really, just a mistake. :) Thanks!

Comment: I'd  get 30 years. is right. befall is not right here at all. caer here would actually be: come down on me